# Decoding a string with python with portuguese characters

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

So I have this text that I pulled from the internet, that some of the words are not using the correct characters, like this one "experiÃªncias". Is there any function or something in python where I could tackle strings like that and turn into the portuguese version. like experiência.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you "pulled" was not a Unicode string but a string in the Western-European encoding, probably CP1252. You must encode it back to the byte object and then decode correctly.

```
"experiÃªncias".encode("cp1252").decode()
# 'experiências'
```

Comment: And you know that the right encoding to do would be cp1252 how? Experience?.. or is there a way to run a random text and check which encoding the text it's been using? Thanks anyways, that solved my problem :)

Comment: Any language has a small set of preferred encodings. Just try one at a time until it comes out right.

Comment: @RenanCidale There are libraries like `chardet` and `unicodedamnit` that do some heuristics to try to guess. But certain patterns of mojibake, especially related to treating Latin-1 (and related encodings like cp1252) like UTF-8 or vice-versa,, are common enough that you do learn them by experience.

Comment: @RenanCidale The problem is that data which use the pre Unicode encodings do not provide any way to tell you which encoding they use. The ISO 8859 standard was a huge mistake. You have to somehow magically know which of the various ISO 8859 encodings the data is in. This includes the MS Windows encodings such as CP1252.